# optimizing this query - which index or changes should i do?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Quite a simple question. But i'm a little bit lost when it come to sql optimization and index, i'm learning.

Query

```
SELECT A.*, count(A.ID) as count 
FROM tableB B 
JOIN tableA A ON A.ID = B.ID 
WHERE B.otherID=xx and B.value='test' and B.languageID=3
```

Table A

```
CREATE TABLE `tableA` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `info1` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `info2` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)
) TYPE=MyISAM
```

Table B

```
CREATE TABLE `tableB` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `otherID` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `value` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `languageID` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`,`otherID`,`languageID`)
) TYPE=MyISAM
```

So the query is quite simple, i'm looking for the fields with a specific id and value in the table B, and i'm doing a join on table A because i need some infos which are in there.
I guess the query itself can't be optimized, but maybe i can speed up thing if i create an index, an index on (B.otherID,B.value) maybe ?

Thanks for you lights!

Comment: Creating indices on the join and where columns should help, assuming MySQL chooses a query plan that uses those indices.

Comment: What is the point of a DISTINCT on `a.ID`? I assume that is an auto increment column and therefore they will all be unique? Or am I wrong

Comment: It might be useful if you show us your schema for these 2 tables

Comment: I added the table structure. And yes, you are right, the distinct is useless here

Comment: Ok, i tried an index on the table B and columns (otherID,value)
And the query is now approx. 10 times faster.

I guess it's the best i can do for this specific query.

Thanks!

Comment: Better, yes; best, no.

Comment: The query doesn't make much sense. It results in one row, because of `count(A.ID)` without a `GROUP BY`. So `A.*` is one A record arbitrarily chosen from the matching ones. So before *optimizing* the query, you might want to *correct* it :-)

Comment: Yep, you are right, but this weirdness was only in the example, the real query actually just do a count.

Answer (score 1):

Normally the name `ID` is used for the `PRIMARY KEY`.  A `PRIMARY KEY` is necessarily Unique.  Yet you say

```
PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`,`otherID`,`languageID`)
```

Is `ID` not unique, but this triple is?  (Just checking.)

Back to your question...

```
WHERE B.otherID=xx and B.value='test' and B.languageID=3
```

Says that `B` needs those 3 columns in a composite index in any order.  With that, the Optimizer will start with `B`, quickly find the row(s) needed there.  Then it will move over to `A`, which already has an index on `ID` to handle `ON A.ID = B.ID`.

[*My Cookbook*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/) on creating indexes.

The normal pattern is `COUNT(*)`.  `COUNT(x)` has the extra burden of checking all the `x` values for being not `NULL`.  (I suspect you did not need that.)

Use InnoDB, not MyISAM.

Comment: Thanks, i wasn't aware of any performance difference between COUNT(*) and COUNT(x).
About the index, actually i just need B.otherID=xx and B.value in the index.
And about the ID, this ID is unique in tableA, in tableB it's there only as a reference.
About using InnoDB over MyISAM, this choice depend of a lot of factor, i don't think you can say : Use InnoDB, point.

Comment: The next version of MySQL will be removing MyISAM.  Essentially every argument in favor of MyISAM has been satisfied by improvements to InnoDB.  The only remaining one is that InnoDB takes more disk space; that cannot be fixed.  (Sorry, I can't think of a good link; search on both myisam and innodb.)